# PHP ftp_delete() generates warning "Command okay"

Tags: php, ftp

I can not find any answer to this as most problems revolve around a file not existing or a delete process not working.

I have an FTP device where I generate a file with an PHP script. After that, I try to FTP in, get the file and after that, delete it.

This all works fine, I can connect, get the file and save it locally and then delete it. Except for one thing, the `ftp_delete()` function results in a warning.

PHP gives me the following, when executing the script:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>      Severity: Warning
>      Message: ftp_delete(): Command okay

I looked up the error code, it means it was successful. And it was because the file is deleted on the FTP device.

So why does this generate an PHP error?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959) (FTP specification) mandates that on a successful completion of the `DELE` command, the server should respond with `250` status code.

The PHP FTP implementation is very strict, yielding a warning on any other code, even if it indicates a success (`2xx` class).

Your server probably uses some other `2xx` code, like a generic `200 Command okay`.

Comment: This explains a lot. I guess i will have to work with the 200 code. Thank you.